# Grails security plugin: avoid cache control response header

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I am using the Grails Security Plugin im my application and I appreciate it really.

Spring security automatically adds several headers to the https responses in order to avoid the caching of sensitive pages in the browser cache. I would like to disable that for non confidential informations like, for instance, fonts.

Native Spring security allows that through the `<http>, <headers> and <cache-control disabled="true">` configuration elements.

While that would be simple with an XML config, I can't figure out the way to add the equivalent of  to the configuration of the security plugin. Any hints?

I am using Grails 3.2.9, and security plugin 3.1.1.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in CacheControlHeadersWriter and see from where its being called, and see how to disable it.

Comment: Thank you Sudhir N. I already tried that but that did not work. The breakpoint is not hit.